# Enable Mpiexec command for multiple users

Tags: amazon-web-services, mpi, ubuntu-10.04

I have implement mpi cluster on ubunto 10.04 using this article
http://byobu.info/article/Building_a_simple_Beowulf_cluster_with_Ubuntu/
but now I have to implement this on cloud and the main problem is that mpiexec is just dedicated for mpiuser. I am unable to use this when command with different users.
please help since i have to provide secure platform to others user on cloud to execute mpiexec command for parallel computation but I don't want them to modify .mpd.conf or mpd.hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your configuration into /etc/mpd.conf to make it available to all users.

Comment: can you please tell me what command should I add in mpd.conf...
thank you for your response